# Accessing a list of avaliable Wifi APs, on Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, windows, compact-framework, mobile

I need to query for a list of available Wireless Access points. I only need their SSIDs.

The App is currently .Net CF 2.0, but it's not a problem going with 3.5 if we have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of "nearby" APs is retrived eitehr through NDIS or WZC, depending on what your NIC driver supports.  Both are somewhat well documented in MSDN, but they aren't fun to wrap.  OpenNETCF's SDF contains a wrapper that looks at both, depending on your  NIC's support.

It's accessible via the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d79a4a4f-93be-3c85-477b-5298d1141978.htm).[NetworkInterface](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d308a2a7-778b-ff94-b297-54422ea9a271.htm)'s [GetAllNetworkInterfaces method](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/2dc21eda-47c6-fde5-e569-1781b1b44feb.htm) in the newest [SDF 2.3](http://smartdeviceframework.com) (actually it's been there since 2.2).

Comment: nice one, a much better reply! +1

Answer (score 1):

Well the core of this is in the Windows Zero Config .dll otherwise known as WZC. However from a managed app you'll want to go via [OpenNETCF](http://www.opennetcf.com/) as they have a managed wrapper that can provide this information for you.
The classes of interest are the Adapter or NetworkAdapter classes.

The obselete api was:

```
Networking.GetAdapters()
```

although this is now depreciated I think and I apologise but i've forgotten what they've replaced it with but there will be a new equivalent.