# How do I get WLAN information on my mobile device?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, wifi

I want to build something like a network scanner, so that I see in my application on which AccessPoint I'm on and what parameters this net has.

Some interesting point would be ESSID, signal strength, noise, channel.

Are theses properties device independent or do I have to interface each device independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, but I believe OpenNetCF is you friend:

http://www.opennetcf.com/library/networkinformation/

Answer (score 0):

This is really the same question as this one: [Accessing a list of avaliable Wifi APs, on Windows Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322070)

The answer, summarized, is that you can P/Invoke WZC, but it's difficult.  The [Smart Device Framework](http://www.smartdeviceframework.com) has it done.